# swift: How to update NSUserDefault?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

So, I want to create my own mini social network. In registration page I have following lines of code:

```
var ns = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()    
let array: [String] = ["\(login!)","\(password!)","\(nameSurname!)", "team", "university"] //team, university
ns.setObject(array, forKey: "\(login)")
```

I just create array and set it to NSUserDefaults.

And also I have page where users can change informations or datas about them, change their password for example. In this page i have following lines of code:

```
let login = loginTextField.text!
        let password = passwordTextField.text!
        let nameSurname = nameSurnameTextField.text!
        let team = teamTextField.text!
        let university = universityTextField.text!

            let ns = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            let array: [String] = ["\(login)","\(password)","\(nameSurname)", "\(team)", "\(university)"] //team, university course
            ns.setObject(array, forKey: "\(login)")
```

Here I create new array and set this new array to KEY-Login. But my datas in NSUserDefaults doesn't change. How I can fix it? What I should do? Thanks)

Comment: You may need to call `ns.synchronize()` after you do `ns.setObject(array, forKey: "\(login)")`.

Comment: `"\(login)"` represents the value from the login text field rather than a constant string `"login"`. Is this really intended?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're treating both arrays the same way.  Because you're using the array as the key for NSUserDefaults, they have to have exactly the same values in each section of code, otherwise you're not updating the first array in the the second array.

Comment: @Larme `synchronize()` is almost always useless https://twitter.com/catfish_man/status/674727133017587712 :)

Comment: no, that one doesn't help me ;(

Comment: @vadian your solution also didn't help ;/

Comment: How (and when) do you **read** the array?

Comment: @fbara no, they are in different view controllers

Comment: @vadian , why i should read array?

Comment: If you never read the array how do you know that the data doesn't change?

Comment: @vadian when i enter to my profile i have print("\(array[3])") which shows me team of user.

Comment: Take a look at this link, it will help you understand how to use NSUserDefaults.  I think part of the problem is you're not understanding correctly how this works.  https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Is no one else going to point out that you shouldn't be saving usernames and especially passwords in plain text in NSUserDefaults? I thought the StackOverflow users here would be all over that.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the issue is here. Firstly change this:

```
    var ns = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() 
    //No need for " quotation marks you are using String vars   
    let array: [String] = [login!, password!, nameSurname!, team, university] 
    ns.setObject(array, forKey: "login")

    //Save the changes 
    ns.synchronize()


    //Now when we want to load the information
    let ns = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let array = ns.objectForKey("login")
    //This prints the users password
    print(array![1])



    //Make some changes
    let newArray = ["new name", password!, nameSurname!, team, university]
    ns.setObject(newArray, forKey: "login")
    //Remember to save
    ns.synchronize()
```

Maks sure you are using `ns.synchronize()`.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the document about the Performance Tradeoffs in NSUserDefaults:

> Reading from NSUserDefaults is extremely fast. It will cache values to
> avoid reading from the disk, and takes about 0.5 microseconds to do
> [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:] on a 2012 MacBook
> Pro. It’s generally unnecessary (and even undesirable since it
> prevents picking up new values) to cache the result of reading from
> preferences.
>
> However, writing to NSUserDefaults is a bit slower. In general, expect
> it to take roughly as long as using NSPropertyListSerialization to
> convert your key and value to plist data, plus a few 10s of
> microseconds. For this reason, as well as memory usage, it’s generally
> best to store relatively small data in CFPreferences.
>
> Long story short, do not use synchronize in iOS 8 and later.